# Help understanding how the triangle inequality is used

Tags: analysis

Why does $\lvert y \rvert\leq\lvert x \rvert+1$ for $y\in(x-1,x+1)$ follow by the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because  the hypothesis on $y$ means  exactly that $|y-x|<1$,  and because we can rewrite $y=(y-x)+x$.

Comment: @Sbastiano: Which ones? I've  seen on about the mixed product. Are there others?